# Reason for returning an rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding-reference

I see a class defined like the following:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  template <typename T, typename... Args>
  Foo&& addElement(Args&&... args) {       <--- why do we return Foo&&
    elements_.emplace_back(
      std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    return std::move(*this);
  }

 private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> elements_;
};
```

I can't think of any good reasons for the returning type of function `addElement()`. Does it make sense to return an rvalue reference, or it is not a good idea? If so, what is the potential reason for doing that?

Comment: That's because `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable but only moveable but I don't see why `addElement` should return the object itself.  I'd use `void` return.

Comment: This is bad practice, don't write this. You will get silent moves like this.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't understand why it's returning Foo&&. I think returning void is better. Agree?

Comment: @PasserBy are you saying my example is bad practice or what Henri said is bad?

Comment: Your snippet is bad. Having side effects where you don't expect is always bad.

Comment: How can we know what was the reason of author of code to return rvalue reference to this? Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: Returning a reference is not unheard of. It's what allows `one.to().chain().calls();` - It looks to me like whoever wrote that wanted to allow chaining, but then misunderstood and thought they need to return an rvalue reference on account of the unique pointer.

Comment: What's the consequences of returning "return std::move(*this);"? Will *this be moved? No, right? this will still be a valid pointer and I don't see any reason of doing so.